# setTimeout function isn't called?

Tags: javascript

To put a delay on a menu onmouseover effect, setTimeout is one of the options.  But when I try it, the function isn't called.

HTML:

```
  <li><a href="#"  
         onmouseover="mopendelay('menu_proj')" 
  <li>
```

JavaScript:

```
// open hidden layer
function mopen(id)
{   
    // cancel close timer
    mcancelclosetime();

    // close old layer
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    // get new layer and show it
    ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
    ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

}

// delay menu open on mouseover
function mopendelay(id) 
{
    var delay = setTimeout(function(){
      alert('delay'); // isn't called
      mopen(id);
    }, 200);
    clearTimeout(delay);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're clearing timeout before the timeout function can execute.

```
function mopendelay(id) 
{
    var delay = setTimeout(function(){
        mopen(id);
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: OK.  Thanks for all the answers.  If I remove clear time out it works.  I must also remove the debug alert statement to get the right response.

Answer (score 2):

You're immediately calling `clearTimeout` on the handle returned by `setTimeout`. Why is that? I believe the code will work as expected if you remove that.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `clearTimeout` directly afterward. Whatever for? Remove that line, and it will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your clear timeout should be outside of the function passed to setTimeout